# Chrome does not display full URL

Tags: google-chrome, url

Chrome (v53) displays the full URL in the address bar if it is https, but not if it is http.

How do I fix this?

e.g. This page displays as
  stackoverflow.com/questions/ask

Copy/paste does collect the full URL:
  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask

Comment: Finally the Chrome product managers have listened - just go in the menu to **View** and toggle **Always show full URL**   

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The display of the "http://" has been removed a few version back. It doesn't look like they will be adding that in again any time soon.

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=41467

It has a status of

> Status:   WontFix

looks like it's here to stay.

Comment: Very sad. Total fail from the Chrome developers.

Comment: Indeed, total fail. Back to Firefox for good.

Comment: Now chrome also hides www

Comment: @ViliusL now they hide *https://* as well. I'd much rather see the full url with protocol and everything. Why isn't there an option somewhere to show the full URL :@:@

Comment: This is now possible for Chrome 69+:

**chrome://flags > Omnibox UI Hide Steady-State URL Scheme and Trivial Subdomains > Disabled**

Comment: Since Chrome 71+ you need to set multiple flags to `disabled` if you want to see full URL by default. Loading `about:flags` and searching for `steady` should list all options that need to be disabled.